Change bytes into petabytes in kusto query
I have a kusto query that have two columns as shown below & size column is in bytes
Database             size
sub1                 2541304016738179270
sub2                 2539224975164406590
How can I change the bytes into petabytes & create a new column next to "size" using "extend" function or a different way?

below are a few options:
datatable(Database: string, size: long)
[
    'sub1', 2541304016738179270,
    'sub2', 2539224975164406590
]
| extend
    option1 = format_bytes(size, 3),
    Petabytes = round(size / exp2(50), 3),
    Exabytes = round(size / exp2(60), 3)




Database
size
option1
Petabytes
Exabytes




sub1
2541304016738179270
2.204 EB
2257.131
2.204


sub2
2539224975164406590
2.202 EB
2255.285
2.202




@ thanks it works.

Could you please share how I can change from GB to PetaBytes?

Can you please raise a new question as it is not a primary ask @HaiY?
